# Ubuntu 13.10: Bad application startup drawing (e.g., chromium)

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, nautilus, chromium

I have always noticed a small graphical performance issue in my ten years experience with GNU/Linux. The problem is related to how applications are drawn when started. Typically, on my machine, when you start an application:

- STEP 1: the window is drawn without any content (e.g., white inside OR black inside, then it is expanded to fullscreen, then filled with some white inside)
- STEP 2: then the GUI toolkit (e.g., GTK 2.x) starts to include some graphical components
- STEP 3: finally, the application is ready to be used

I recorded two videos: [the first one shows the startup of Chromium](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9ueeFUCQlw&feature=youtu.be), while [the second one is related to Nautilus](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9wfAEjIIDs&feature=youtu.be) (I have killed Nautilus before recording). I can notice the same problem with QT4/KDE applications.

I would like that steps 1 and 2 are executed in "background" and the application is shown only when the application content is fully drawn/ready (step 3). Steps 1, 2, 3 typically happen in 0-2 seconds, therefore waiting for step 3 is not a huge problem (IMAO).

How can I fix this issue? Steps 1-2 are really annoying to be seen.

My setup:

- Ubuntu 13.10 amd64
- Unity/Compiz (default configuration, disabled Animations and Fade Windows effects but they did not improve the situation when enabled)
- Nvidia 319.32 (installed with proprietary driver wizard)
- Intel Core 2 Duo 2.0Ghz, 4GB RAM, Nvidia GeForce 9400M

But I have seen this problem on many machines (Intel/AMD/Nvidia/open source drivers/closed drivers)

P.s. This is not a hardware issue (my graphic card is not the best) because other operating systems behave correctly.